Transfer Token Among Account In Aptos MOVE
I'm very new to Aptos Move, can you guys help me to make the transfer action clear?
I'm trying to write some unit tests about collecting collateral tokens and paying some myself-defined tokens, below is one of my unit tests,
 let (burn_cap, mint_cap) = aptos_coin::initialize_for_test(framework);
 let user_signer = &create_account_for_test(@0x13514cc); 
 coin::register<aptos_coin::AptosCoin>(user_signer);
 coin::deposit(signer::address_of(user_signer), coin::mint(10000000, &mint_cap));

This helps me to create a new account and mint some aptos_coin::AptosCoin tokens for testing. But when transferring, I got some confused things, e.g. The receiver in the transfer action has to contain a store itself? (I got an error when the receiver doesn't). I think it's better to create a store automatically if the receiver doesn't implement one
